# 1an1 mysql ip address location

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect my class project to my server (1and1) and am having difficulty. It seems the correct answer is to not use the host name they provided me with but their IP address instead. Where can I find that address to the mysql db or do I need to wait until they are open and call?

Comment: may be this is your host ip not db name

Comment: I meant to say host name. Looking at what they provided, db name is something else.

Comment: @user3066791 You need to check with them that whether they allow remote db access or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was something stupid. My domain was set to PHP4.0 and was using a PDO command which wasn't introduced until 5.2. Changed it to 5.5 and it started working. Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. ServerName=IP address

   They would have provided the ip address of the server to you. You can use the IP address.
2. ServerName=HostName

   If you don't know the ip address right now, you can use the host name as server name. Like:

   `ServerName="www.myhostaddress.com"`

Both work for me all the time.

Comment: They provided me with this. db524322366.db.1and1.com. it shows up bad. i'll give www.1and1.com a shot

Comment: @user3066791: Did you solve the issue? If yes, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others who come across with the same kind of doubts in future.

Comment: No I haven't. started new job so free time is missing. I am trying to squeeze in edit time where I can.